# .find() в JQuery не присваивает результат?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой кусок кода

```
        this.$root = $(selector);
        this.$wrap = this.$root.find('.wrapper');
```

И в переменную $wrap не присваивается результат

```
this.$root.find('.wrapper');
```

Если выводить его просто в console.log, то видно что элемент оно находит. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Что вы дальше делаете с this.$wrap ?

Comment: ну хотя бы добавляю класс
this.$wrap.addClass('wrapper_expanded');

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример где это можно воспроизвести.

Comment: https://playcode.io/706064/
там open и close не используются ни где, это просто как пример как я хочу использоваь this.$wrap

Comment: Похоже, что вялые ссылки к объекту удаляет GC по завершению работы функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(selector) {
  this.$root = $(selector);
  this.render(); //Сначала рендерим
  this.$wrap = this.$root.find('.dropdown__wrap'); // Потом ищем
}
render() {
  this.$root.html(template());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам правильно указали в ответе @Ordman. Я лишь перенёс код и добавил комментариев

```js
const template = () => {
    return `
    <div class="dropdown__wrap">
        Test
    </div>
  `
}
class Dropdown{
    constructor(selector) {
    this.$root = $(selector);
    this.$wrap = this.$root.find('.dropdown__wrap'); // тут еще нет его    
    console.log(this.$wrap.length);
    this.render(); // появляется после 
    this.$wrap = this.$root.find('.dropdown__wrap'); // тут есть
    console.log(this.$wrap.length);
  }
    render() {
        this.$root.html(template());
    }
  
    open() {
        this.$wrap.addClass('dropdown__wrap_expanded');
    }

    close() {
        this.$wrap.removeClass('dropdown__wrap_expanded');
    }
}

const dropdown = new Dropdown("#dropdown");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown"></div>
```